# Cypher-Spring Neo4j - Returning 2 nodes on the same time

Tags: spring, neo4j, cypher

Hi I have this situation below:

> **MOVE 1** : **FROM** pointA **TO** pointD 
> **MOVE 2** :
>   **FROM** pointA **TO** pointB 
> **MOVE 3** : **FROM** pointA **TO** pointC 
> **MOVE 4** : **FROM** pointC **TO** pointD 
> **MOVE 5**
>   : **FROM** pointB **TO** pointD

I want to go from pointA to pointD and I need to return the path(MOVE) that I need to follow:

I just did this query:

> **START**  f=node(1),t=node(2) 
> **MATCH** 
>   f<-[r1:FROM]-move1-[r2:TO]->point<-[r3:FROM]-move2-[r4:TO]->t
>   
> **RETURN** move1,move2

and it returned:

```
 _________________
| NODE   |  NODE  |
|--------|--------| 
| Move 2 | Move 5 |
| Move 3 | Move 4 |
|_________________|
```

I like the return, but has some points that It fails

1st) It missed the **MOVE 1**
*** I can build another query if doesn't have another way

2nd) I don't know how to work with it returning 2 nodes, if it return a list of nodes, i can the code below, but if it return the Node(move 2) and the Node(move 5) on the same time how can I work with this situation?

```
@Query("f=node({id}) MATCH f<-[r1:FROM]-move1")
Iterable<Move> moves (@Param("id")Long id);
```

here my console with my issue:

http://console.neo4j.org/?id=ln3w9c

Can someone advise?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to find all MOVES that can take you from Point A to Point B. If this is the case, below is the query

```
MATCH p=a-[:MOVE_TO*]->b 
WHERE a.name='A' AND b.name='D' 
RETURN p
```

You can test it by going to [the console here](http://console.neo4j.org/r/jrm9y6). (I've setup the test data for you). Below is the setup Cypher I've used

```
CREATE (pointA { name:'A'})
CREATE (pointB { name:'B'}) 
CREATE (pointC { name:'C'}) 
CREATE (pointD { name:'D'}) 
CREATE pointA-[:MOVE_TO]->pointD 
CREATE pointA-[:MOVE_TO]->pointB 
CREATE pointA-[:MOVE_TO]->pointC 
CREATE pointC-[:MOVE_TO]->pointD 
CREATE pointB-[:MOVE_TO]->pointD
```

Comment: @user2551955 If I've answered your question, up vote and accept this as the answer.

Comment: It works very well, but in this case is necessary that the MOVE is a node. MOVE has others relationship like WHO did the move.

Comment: @user2551955 This is just an example of how to solve your issue. Change it the way the fits you better

Comment: I really dont understand how can i change it to use it on my case

Comment: I have, a nodes (points and moves), i need to know the moves that is a node like pointA<-[:FROM]-MOVE1-[:TO]->pointB

Comment: @user2551955 Can you setup the data in console and share the link

Comment: Hi here it is: http://console.neo4j.org/?id=ln3w9c I need to rerutnr only the MOVE(path)

Comment: @user2551955 I am unable to come up with a query that returns what you need. If you need to store additional details in relationships you can do so as neo4j supports relationship props as well. So in your case you can add a "who" property to the MOVE_TO reltionship.